# Difficulty understanding relation A ⊂ B between events A and B

Tags: terminology

My lecturer is adamant that the following is true and I'm struggling to get my head around it:

"relation A ⊂ B between two events A and B means that the event A occurs whenever event B does, but not necessarily the opposite."

My understanding is that this notation means that A is a proper subset of B. It makes sense to me that the opposite would be true - that event B occurs whenever event A does, but not necessarily the opposite, because there are elements of B that are not in A. Can someone please explain why I'm wrong?

Comment: I think it is you who is correct.

Comment: Your reasoning is not in sync with your conclusion.

Comment: @StubbornAtom please can you explain why

Comment: @YS731 $A$ is a subset of $B$. This means that $A$ is contained in the bigger set $B$. So whenever $B$ occurs, $A$ necessarily occurs as every element of $A$ is in $B$. But there may be elements of $B$ not in $A$ ( as $B$ is the bigger set), so occurrence of $A$ does not necessarily imply occurrence of $B$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I think maybe we differ on what it means for an event to occur... My understanding is that an event occurs whenever any of its elements are an outcome of the experiment. It doesn't have to be all of its elements. So if a single element of A is an outcome, A has occurred. That same element is an element of B, because A is a proper subset of B, so B has also occurred. Like you said, there are elements of B not in A that can be an outcome, so B occurring doesn't mean A has occurred.

Comment: @YS731 That is indeed how events are defined in probability work.

Comment: Are you sure that your lecturer did use $\subset$ as (set) inclusion ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA he used that symbol and then showed a venn diagram of a small circle (A) inside a big circle (B). Could there be another meaning for the symbol? I did wonder if maybe he meant implication

Answer (score 4):

Suppose your outcomes are: (r)ain, (s)shine), (d)rizzle, (h)ail.  So your sample space is $\Omega = \{r, s, d, h\}$.

Now, let $A$ be the event "rain or shine": $A = \{r, s\}$, and let $B$ be the event "rain or shine or hail": $B = \{r, s, h\}$.

If the weather is "hail" (outcome $h$), then event $B$ has occurred, but event $A$ has not.

However, if $A$ occurs, then so necessarily does $B$.

Comment: Yeah.. this seems to be in agreement with what I thought